# I launch the bot's telegram, there are no errors, I write an SMS to the bot and errors pop up, what's the problem?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

```
C:\Users\xxlda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe C:/Users/xxlda/PycharmProjects/python-telegram-bot/app.py
Cause exception while getting updates.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxlda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 359, in start_polling
    updates = await self.bot.get_updates(limit=limit, offset=offset, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\xxlda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 95, in get_updates
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.GET_UPDATES, payload)
  File "C:\Users\xxlda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 200, in request
    return await api.make_request(self.session, self.__token, method, data, files,
  File "C:\Users\xxlda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 104, in make_request
    return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
  File "C:\Users\xxlda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 82, in check_result
    exceptions.ConflictError.detect(description)
  File "C:\Users\xxlda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\exceptions.py", line 137, in detect
    raise err(cls.text or description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.TerminatedByOtherGetUpdates: Terminated by other getupdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running
Cause exception while getting updates.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxlda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 359, in start_polling
    updates = await self.bot.get_updates(limit=limit, offset=offset, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\xxlda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 95, in get_updates
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.GET_UPDATES, payload)
  File "C:\Users\xxlda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 200, in request
    return await api.make_request(self.session, self.__token, method, data, files,
  File "C:\Users\xxlda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 104, in make_request
    return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
  File "C:\Users\xxlda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 82, in check_result
    exceptions.ConflictError.detect(description)
  File "C:\Users\xxlda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\exceptions.py", line 137, in detect
    raise err(cls.text or description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.TerminatedByOtherGetUpdates: Terminated by other getupdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running
```

I launch the bot's telegram, there are no errors, I write an SMS to the bot and errors pop up, what's the problem?

here is the link not github, there is my bot completely-https://github.com/bloodyt3ars/python-telegram-bot.git

Answer (score 0):

make sure that only one bot instance is running , it means you should be only person you use that bot token on the time, make sure you don't run the bot on any server like heroku... or with another console after that you can run the code